# Cursor always returning null on query

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I'm using an Intent to select a file from my Android device. When shown the Chooser, I select the Astro file manager and then procede to select a file (a video in this case).

I get back a URI (`content://com.metago.astro.filecontent/file/file/sdcard/Download/video_video.mp4`) and I'm trying to process it with the following:

```
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = null;
    final String[] projection = null;

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // Never enters here because cursor always null
            L.p("Hi!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        L.p(e.getMessage()); // Never hit
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
```

however cursor always returns `null` . Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Perhaps Astro does not support the `OpenableColumns`. They should, IMHO, at least if you have `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` on the `Intent` that you used to "select a file".

Comment: I tried adding `videoIntent.addCategory(CATEGORY_OPENABLE);` but I still get `null`.

Comment: Are you sure that this is not throwing some exception? You do not show the `catch` block and whether you are logging anything.

Comment: Yep, it's null but doesn't throw an Exception. I've updated the snippet. PS Thanks for your time.

Comment: Based on your description, it would appear to be a bug in Astro. You may wish to contact them and see what they have to say. Either that, or work around the fact that you cannot retrieve the `OpenableColumns`. Those only give you a display name and a size. For the display name, use `getLastPathSegment()` on the `Uri` to snip off the filename, since their `Uri` happens to work that way.